# Unable to retrieve value from previous page asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void btnAddtoCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int qty = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);
        try
        {
            string connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AUMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
            string command = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails( ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, OrderQuantity, UserName) VALUES(@ProductID, @ProductName, @UnitPrice, @OrderQuantity, @UserName)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, myConnect);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", Convert.ToInt16**(ProductID))**;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @ProductName", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderQuantity",qty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session["UserName"].ToString());
            myConnect.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

I am unable to retrieve `ProductID` from the previous page but the code below works.

```
string command = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, OrderBaseID, ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, OrderQuantity, AccountID) VALUES(1, 1, "+ Convert.ToInt16(ProductID) + ",'" + name + "','19.00',5,'Lewis')";
```

Can anyone tell me what is the error? I've tried to debug but the value returned is null.

Comment: How are you storing and retrieving `ProductID`?

Comment: string ProductID = Request.QueryString["listingID"]; iam using the ProductID to open up a new page

Comment: Post code where where you store this in QueryString.